I couldnt find this at Home Depot. What should I use to replace it?
Home Depot doesn't carry these. I am not familiar with these and have never replaced one. Seems pretty easy to replace though. More concerned with brand and quality. I am not sure if I should buy the same thing from Keystone or a different brand.

I found it on Amazon for $18

Why are you replacing it? Are you sure it is bad and not the bulbs or something else? Do you have any intention of switching to LEDs in the near future or are you (for any reason - and there can be good reasons) committed to staying with fluorescent bulbs?

Did you know that there are stores that specialize in electrical parts? They'll carry far more than any big-box store will, and their employees will actually know what they're talking about.

That's called a ballast, get them from ballastshop.com or 1000bulbs.com.  "I only shop at Home Depot" fix that. "but it has the best prices" they lie.

It is a fluorescent ballast.
IMO the best approach if this has failed is to replace the entire fixture with an LED one, or to replace the bulbs with LED ballast-bypass ones. Then you can just discard this without replacing it.
If you want to keep your fluorescent bulbs for some reason, you can replace the ballast with any one that:

is rated for your bulbs. EG, if your fixture has two F20T12 bulbs, get a ballast that supports that.
will physically fit in the fixture. I can't see how it's mounted, clips or screws or what, but the new one has to be compatible.


You can replace a T12 (way old fashioned, tubes hard to find now) with a T8 when you are replacing the ballast, as the tubes are the same length with the same pins. But the ballasts are different. The Despot is not a good place to find such things. Be very careful "where your vendor is" if you chose to buy from Bezos, as direct import crap is a large part of his business model. There are reputable in-country distributors that sell non-counterfeit parts on the net.

@Ecnerwal what is a reputable online dealer if I can't find it locally?

@jay613 what would I need to do to replace it with an LED one? What would I need to do to find a compatible LED ballast? Could I just replace the ballast or would I need to replace the whole fixture?

You can replace the whole fixture, sometimes Costco has new ones at crazy low price.  Or you can get led bulbs that are long tube shaped to fit these sockets and do not require ballasts.  You rewire the lamp for them.  There are also led tube lamps, direct replacements, that do work with ballasts.  Don't get those.
